# How to update ms access database with parameters c#

Tags: c#

I am trying to update my ms access db with windows application and I am having a hard time. When I run it I don't get any errors but it does update like once or twice when I test it but then doesn't work again if I do it again a third time.

This is the code I use

```
Conn.Open();
Command.CommandType = CommandType.Text;
Command.CommandText ="UPDATE TABLE SET c_qty=@qty WHERE id = @ID";

Command.Parameters.AddWithValue("@qty", txtQty.Text);
Command.Parameters.AddWithValue("@ID", txtID.Text);
Command.ExecuteNonQuery();
Conn.Close();
```

I felt I was doing this right or on the right track of having it correct but seems to be more of a issue then I thought. Any help would be great

Comment: The OleDB provider for MS Access does *not* support **named** parameters like `@ID` - it only supports **positional** parameters. So it doesn't matter how you name your parameters - what you really need to be careful about is to specify them in the **correct order** in which they appear in your SQL statement (which is the case, here, in your example)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

- Quantity and Id are *hopefully* integers and you should pass them as such.
- Also `Table` is a reserved word, if this really is the name of your table you should enclose it with square brackets.
- You should also pass in the correct db types in your parameters and not use `AddWithvalue` which does not allow this.

Code

```
Conn.Open();
Command.CommandType = CommandType.Text;
Command.CommandText ="UPDATE [TABLE] SET c_qty= ? WHERE id = ?";

Command.Parameters.Add(new OleDbParameter("@qty", OleDbType.Int) {Value = int.Parse(txtQty.Text)});
Command.Parameters.Add(new OleDbParameter("@ID",  OleDbType.Int) {Value = int.Parse(txtID.Text)});
var rowsUpdated = Command.ExecuteNonQuery();
// output rowsUpdated to the log, should be 1 if id is the PK
Conn.Close();
```

Finally use `using` blocks for your Disposables. If you were to get an Exception here then connection would remain open until Garbage collection runs which means you might have a problem with other connection attempts to this Access database.

Revised with `using` blocks

```
using (OleDbConnection Conn = new OleDbConnection("connectionStringHere"))
using (OleDbCommand Command = new OleDbCommand("UPDATE [TABLE] SET c_qty= ? WHERE id = ?", Conn))
{
    Command.Parameters.Add(new OleDbParameter("@qty", OleDbType.Int) {Value = int.Parse(txtQty.Text)});
    Command.Parameters.Add(new OleDbParameter("@ID",  OleDbType.Int) {Value = int.Parse(txtID.Text)});
    Conn.Open();

    var rowsUpdated = Command.ExecuteNonQuery();
    // output rowsUpdated to the log, should be 1 if id is the PK
}
```

Finally OleDbCommand does not support named parameters, see [OleDbCommand.Parameters](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.data.oledb.oledbcommand.parameters(v=vs.110).aspx)

Comment: its not the name its just what I put for posting on here.. I will give your code a try

Comment: That worked. I had to tweak it to make it work but it does work now thanks for the help.

Comment: Can you verify for me if I would do this same for inserting?

Comment: @Don - correct. `INSERT INTO [TABLENAME] (column1,column2,column3,...) VALUES (?,?,?,?....)` and provide your parameters in order.